# How to View Watched Tags on Stack Overflow when unable to increase page width

Tags: support, design, tag-watching

I am often on the road and I use my Android device to view questions on Stack Overflow. I always set my view to 'Desktop site' as the options are so very limited when not viewing in that mode. However today I noticed that I am still lacking many features when viewing Stack Overflow questions from my phone. After logging into my laptop once I returned home I realized that this is an issue with page 'Width'.

The Watched Tags live in the right hand pane. If there is not enough space this pane is not visible.

**Question (To the point)**

> Is there any other place to edit/view watched tags or is there a way to force the right pane visible regardless of width?

Even on a laptop, the right pane is only visible if my browser decides there is enough space. I navigate my watched tags often to view questions in areas I am familiar with. How do I accomplish this navigation without the right pane?

Screenshots below:

**Right Pane Visible**

[image: Right Pane Visible]

**Width too small to view Right Pane Options**

[image: Right Pane Not Visible]

Comment: Not ideal UI but right sidebar should be visible under questions list . In your user preferences you can also control visibility of left sidebar to show permanently or turn into dropdown menu

Comment: One possibility is to use the `Disable Responsiveness` option at the bottom left of each page. Then you can simply scroll right to see the sidebar

Comment: @user36296 You mentioned that I could possibly try to `Disable Responsiveness` and that it can be found on the bottom left of each page.  I do not have any options at the bottom left of the pages I am viewing on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @charlietfl Where would I navigate to access `User Preferences`.  Are you referring my Stack Overflow user preferences?  Or is this a browser type setting you are referring to?

Comment: @CodeNovice On your SO profile page ... *Edit profile and settings* tab then *Preferences* under Site Settings heading

Comment: @CodeNovice This button https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt8zt.png in the footer of every page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right sidebar is displaced below the question list when the screen is small enough:

[image: image of watched tags near end of scrollbar position]

Comment: This is also good to know.  I simply just never found myself scrolling all the way to the bottom of the questions list all too often which is also where the option to disable responsiveness lives - very bottom.  I just want to note that this in addition to hiding the left sidebar options and also `Disabling Responsiveness` are all ways to gain access to the `Watched Tags`.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer with the other methods if they are useful. I just added an answer where I found them. It's totally okay and encouraged for you to answer your own question, even if someone answers in a comment (they should have answered in an answer :)).